# Can every non-negative log-concave function $f(x)$ be represented as $a \cdot c(x) \cdot h(x)$?

Tags: calculus, statistics, functions

I'm working on a piece of research in Statistics and would need to show the following claim is true: let $f(x)$ be a continuous, non-negative log-concave function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^+$. It is **always** possible to represent it as 
$$ f(x) = a \cdot c(x) \cdot h(x),$$ with $a \geq 0$ and $c(x)$ and $h(x)$ both non-negative and log-concave. The idea is that the product $c(x)h(x)$ is non-negative and log-concave and $a$ would be there to ensure equality.

A trivial example where the claim is true is for $a = 1$ and $c(x) = h(x) = \sqrt{f(x)}$, so I guess the **always** bit above is not a difficulty, but I may be ignoring some subtleties.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have answered the question yourself.

Comment: I might have, but want to know if the "answer" is airtight.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Your answer is clean and air/water tight!